# FatalError: Class 'CakeSession' not found in 'C:/Apache24'

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, httpd.conf

I have a Cake app. Suddenly, I started having this error when I enable debug, and page is blank in browser.

> FatalError: Class 'CakeSession' not found in 'C:/Apache24'
>       \htdocs\lib\Cake\ViewHelper\SessionHelper on line 44.

Why is Cake looking for CakeSession in C:/Apache24?

I have Apache 2.4 over a Windows Server. I think someone changed something in the httpd.conf file. The documentRoot is pointing to the correct path (C:/Apache24/htdocs).

Appreciate the help

Comment: So the code at line #44 is?...........

Comment: Yes, in the SessionHelper::44 there's a function:
public function read($name = null){
return CakeSession::read($name)
}

Seems like Cake is not finding system classes

Comment: delete all your cache files and try again

Comment: Hi @mcgowan, could you let me know where cache and sessions files are supposed to be stored, cause /app/tmp/cache and /app/tmp/sessions (where i guess these files could be) are empty.
Thanks!

Comment: post an image of the directory structure of your document root folder